# Git shows modified files after cloning from another repository

Tags: git, gitlab

When I clone from another repository. After a while, I saw modified and deleted files when running *git status* from other contributors. *Git diff* show actually code changes not the kind of "end of line" thing.

After I clone the repository. I still see the git branch name of that project.

```
public_html git:(develop)
```

I am not sure about the git workflow in this case. How can I contribute to this repository (gitlab)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer just adds and commits your work as usual.